# Complex queries through multiple models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is going to get kind of long, but I'm self taught, and I'm afraid I'm making some sort of fundamental error that is causing me lots of issues - so I'm going to be really thorough.

The setup (simplified of course - and I had to change the names so if you see a typo, that's not the issue, sorry):

```
class Deviceapi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :devices
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :deviceapis
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :templates, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :designs, through: :templates
  has_many :deviceapis, through: :devices
  has_and_belongs_to_many :devices
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :designs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
end
```

The explanation:

My program receives data from a device - each data entry creates a deviceapi entry in my database. This data is then used by the templates and designs. Users don't have access to the devices (except admins), and no one actually accesses the deviceapis at all.

Now, I want to be able to write queries such as:

```
class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
  # This counts the number of api entries associated with the design
  self.campaign.user.devices.deviceapis.count
end
```

Further, admins should be able to restrict users access to devices as desired.  Which should indirectly restrict access to deviceapis, since they are only accessible through devices anyway (they don't have any view pages or anything).

Specifically, my schema (simplified) shows:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: ################) do
  create_table "deviceapis", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "api_id"
  end

  create_table "devices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "device_guid"
    t.integer  "user_ids"
  end

  create_table "designs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "device_id"
  end
end
```

Queries should automatically be restricted to instances where device_guid (device) and api_id (deviceapi) match. Then it should be further restricted by user_ids (device) matching the user_id (the primary key of user).  Then even more restricted by the device_id (design) matching the device_id (primary key of device).

Scopes and methods can handle the queries once I get them working, but I can't get the queries to do anything but come up empty or spit out errors. I think I'm needing some join tables or something.

How would I build proper join tables for this? Or is there some other, much more obvious way to do this that I'm not seeing? I've spent a long time on this, and I'm learning a lot in trial by fire, but not really making any progress on this specific issue - and I think it's crippling me in other places.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: First error: design.rb `belongs_to :user` is missing. Not sure if this solve the problem though. Just give it a go.

Comment: Your structure is a bit funny too. you have created a loop between user, template and design. FYI: in RDBMS if you encounter a loop, it means something is not right in your architecture.

Comment: I added belongs_to :user for design.rb, but it didn't really seem to affect anything.  There isn't any loop - designs belongs to templates, and templates belong to users (and designs belong to users through templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think will be the issue.

If you log  this:
`Placement.campaign.user.devices` you would get some results. ( I don't know the relation in `Placement` and `Campaign` so I am just guessing.

In your Console do this: ( Based on the above assumptions )
`Placement.campaign.user.devices.class` you should get something like this : `Device::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` or similar.

You will not be able to do this now `Placement.campaign.user.devices.deviceapi` as Rails don't know which one of the record you need the `deviceapi`.

If you do something like this `Placement.campaign.user.devices.first.deviceapi` then you should get result also if you do `Placement.campaign.user.devices.first.deviceapi.class` you should get something like this `Deviceapi` or something similar.

To query the number of `deviceapi` use `join` with condition.

Something like this `User.joins(devices: (:deviceapis) ).where('users.id = ?', current_user.id).count`

I assumed you have the `current_user` available or put some other condition that you think it fits.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: This almost works. When I do in console `Placement.find(1).campaign.user.devices.first.deviceapi` I just get an empty array [ ] (not a nil)

I think the reason, is that I need the deviceapi and the device linked, but **not** by primary key. Specifically, all deviceapi entries have an api_id, which matches one of the device's device_guid. So the join table should show those, but it just keeps coming up empty.

I don't want to do a `Cameraapi.where( stuff )` query if I can avoid it, as users shouldn't have any access to that stuff, and I don't want to leave that code lying around.

Comment: I figured it out, I used:
`has_many :deviceapis, primary_key: "device_guid", foreign_key: "device_id"` and visa-versa. But you certainly got me on the right path, thanks!